# Error: Invalid column name when trying to filter on an aliased column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following code gives me this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'AdvertisementsPrinted'.

I need to apply a `AdvertisementsPrinted > 0`, how can I tweak my code?

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(hh, DateCreated) AS Hour,
    AdvertisementId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsPrinted = 1 THEN IsPrinted END) AS AdvertisementsPrinted
FROM 
    dbo.GaAnalytics
WHERE 
    AdvertisementId IS NOT NULL AND AdvertisementsPrinted > 0
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(hh, DateCreated),
    AdvertisementId
ORDER BY 
    AdvertisementsPrinted DESC
```

Comment: HAVING AdvertisementsPrinted > 0

Comment: @demas thanks for your coment but If I add HAVING AdvertisementsPrinted > 0  before the ORDER BY I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. `WHERE AdvertisementId IS NOT NULL AND AdvertisementsPrinted > 0` - `AdvertisementsPrinted` is an aggregate, so it should be in the `HAVING` clause.
2. You cannot use an alias from the `SELECT` in any other clause of the query except `ORDER BY`. This is because `SELECT` is evaluated after the other clauses like `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` is the last one.

Therefore, change your query to this:

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hh, DateCreated) as Hour,
AdvertisementId,
COUNT(case when IsPrinted = 1 then IsPrinted end) as AdvertisementsPrinted
FROM dbo.GaAnalytics
WHERE AdvertisementId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
DATEPART(hh, DateCreated),
AdvertisementId
HAVING COUNT(case when IsPrinted = 1 then IsPrinted end) > 0
ORDER BY AdvertisementsPrinted DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace AdvertisementsPrinted by COUNT(case when IsPrinted = 1 then IsPrinted end)

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hh, DateCreated) as Hour,
AdvertisementId,
COUNT(case when IsPrinted = 1 then IsPrinted end) as AdvertisementsPrinted
FROM dbo.GaAnalytics
WHERE AdvertisementId IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(case when IsPrinted = 1 then IsPrinted end)> 0
GROUP BY
DATEPART(hh, DateCreated),
AdvertisementId
```

Comment: It does not work, I get error An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.